# MPP 101 Printer & Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, printers

I want to create an android application (phone) which connect to MPP 101 Bluetooth printer and print some texts and a picture.
Is this task feasible to do?
If so can someone help me to find some useful material to to this task.

Comment: Hi, I have the same requirement. Could you find any useful material for this?

Comment: I was able to develop a android app for MPP 101 printer.
You can find its [software manual](http://www.megatron.fr/imprimantes/pdf/manuels/thermal/mpp101/doc_mpp101_soft_e12.pdf) from the product site.
You can mail them to clarify the software manual if you have any doubts.

Comment: Hi, glad if you can provide some more details. I could follow the manual & implement the code. But it couldn't create SPP Connection with the printer using a well known SPP UUID. I tried using 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB as UUID but it failed to establish the connection with printer & throws following exception.
java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:377)